# Importando bibliotecas locais no GO

Tags: golang, library

Estou com dificuldades para fazer a importação de uma biblioteca do do go. A biblioteca esta em uma pasta no mesmo diretório do projeto e sempre da erro da importação, quando não da erro de importação, da erro para acessar a função.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "./test"
)

func main(){
    test.makeCalc(1,1)
    fmt.Println("test.makeCalc(3,6)")
}
```

**test.go**

```
package test

func makeCalc(x int, y int) int{
    return x+y
}
```

Comment: em que local esta seu projeto? dentro da `GOROOT`?

Comment: não, está em uma pasta normal `/home/user/projecst/go/test/`

Comment: De acordo com a [especificação](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations), a interpretação do caminho do `import` depende da implementação do compilador.  Recomendo usar o `import` com o nome canônico do pacote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente crie a seguinte estrutura de pastas:

```
/path/to/app
  |-main.go
  |-src
     |-test
        |-test.go
```

Certifique-se que `/path/to/app` está incluso em GOPATH.
Caso contrário, inclua-o:

```
$ # em linux
$ cd /path/to/app
$ export GOPATH=$GOPATH:/path/to/app
```

O código que está em test.go, para ser usado em main.go, precisa ser exportado, logo use:

```
package test

func MakeCalc(x int, y int) int{
    return x+y
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: De acordo com a documentação, **GOPATH** é a pasta onde fica a área de trabalho. Pelo que entendi, ela não pode ser composta de múltiplos caminhos. Para definir esta variável no _bash_ usar `$ export GOPATH=/pasta/para/a/area/de/trabalho`. referencia: [Setting GOPATH](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH)

Comment: Sim, ela pode ser composta por multiplos locais! A diferença é que o primeiro local definido será o local onde será instalado, por padrão, as bibliotecas que serão instaladas durante a fase de preparação do projeto.