# Como funcionam módulos locais em Go?

Tags: golang

Vi nesta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297946/importando-bibliotecas-locais-no-go) que é possível definir módulos locais em Go usando o `GOPATH`. No entanto, na solução da referida pergunta, não se utiliza o arquivo `go.mod` Para que serve esse arquivo? Existe uma forma de importar pacotes definidos dentro de uma pasta sem precisar adicionar o código fonte no `GOPATH`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para criar um módulo, basta usar:

```
go mod init github.com/seunome/seumodulo
```

Isso criará o `go.mod`. Suponho que faça um `push` desse pacote contra o `github.com/seunome/seumodulo`, você poderá pegar esse pacote de lá, futuramente.

Note: você pode ter vários pacotes dentro de um único módulo, então ao criar novos módulos você deve ter uma boa razão para fazer isso. Você não precisa criar um módulo para cada pacote. Pessoalmente, eu só crio módulos quando pretendo compartilha-lo, ou reutilizar em outros projetos.

---

Então, vamos supor que você tenha o `meuprojeto` que quer usar o `seumodulo`: primeiro o `meuprojeto` também deve ser um módulo, ou seja, também use:

```
go mod init github.com/seunome/meuprojeto
```

Para consumir o "meumodulo" criado anteriormente, você pode simplesmente usar:

```
go get github.com/seunome/seumodulo
```

Esse comando **deve ser executado dentro da pasta que há o `go.mod`**, se não vai dar errado. Dessa forma, o `seumodulo` estará disponível para uso dentro do `meuprojeto`.

---

Se o seu pacote estiver em outra pasta, localmente armazenado, você pode usar o `replace` no `go.mod`:

```
replace github.com/seunome/seumodulo => ../caminho/para/o/seumodulo
```

Dessa forma, ao invés de obter e usar a informação do repositório do GitHub, você usará a da pasta especificada. Isso é útil caso esteja fazendo trabalhado num branch/fork para o `seumodulo`.

---

Se os eu repositório for privado, você pode usar algo como:

```
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOPRIVATE=github.com/seunome/*
```

Dessa forma, conseguirá dar o `go get` num repositório privado.

Answer (score 1):

A solução da pergunta está correta e funciona mesmo nas versões mais recentes de Go. No entanto, desde a versão 1.11 é possível usar um gerenciador de módulos que faz com que seja possível definir pacotes dentro de uma pasta em particular, sem recorrer ao `GOPATH`.

Digamos, por exemplo, que você quer criar um módulo chamado `mymath` para definir operações matemáticas personalizadas. Para isso, crie um novo diretório com o nome do módulo, e navegue até ele:

```
mkdir mymath
cd mymath
```

Para iniciar o módulo use:

```
go mod init mymath
```

Esse comando irá criar um arquivo chamado `go.mod`.

Agora você pode começar a criar os pacotes. Como exemplo, vamos definir `power` como um pacote para operações envolvendo expoentes. Para isso criamos um arquivos chamado `operations.go` (esse nome não é importante) dentro de um subdiretório chamado `power`:

```golang
package power

func Power2(number int) int {
    return number*number
}
```

Para testar que nosso pacote está funcionando, basta criar um arquivo (digamos, `main.go`) na raiz do diretório `mymath`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "mymath/power"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(power.Power2(9))
}
```

Para confirmar que a importação funciona rode:

```
go run main.go

81
```